# Jedi Gear and Weaponry

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

What gear/weaponry do jedi or sith carry other than lightsabers? In the prequels, breathing capsules are used to access the Gungan city, but no other gear is used. This is despite the clear presence of other devices on the Jedi's belts.

Answer (score 5):

As stated [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48389/70236), Jedi and Sith are mostly monks and mystics, sometimes dubbing as <s>aggressive</s> negotiators. Thus, they don't need much equipment, especially the kind of equipment warriors would use (unless there is a war).

These are some tools Jedi carried, with pictures from *Star Wars: Episode 1 - Visual Dictionary* (as pointed out by Valorum):

- [Comlink](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hush-98_comlink); used mostly in prequels

[image: comlink]

- [Utility belt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_utility_belt); used mostly in prequels, containing all sorts of stuff (containing the breathing tool, for example)

[image: utility belt]

- [Breather](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A99_aquata_breather); used for field operations in prequels (hat tip to Valorum).

[image: breather]

- [Imagecaster](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imagecaster/Canon); used a communications and demonstration tool in both original trilogy and the prequels.

[image: imagecaster]

- [Grappling hook](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Grappling_spike_launcher); used in original trilogy by Luke (sort of), and in prequels, by Qui-Gon.

[image: grappling hook]

Comment: Since all of these images are taken directly from the Star Wars: Episode 1 - Visual Dictionary, you might want to quote a source.

Comment: Also, you've forgotten their aquata breather which I presume is *inside* the breather pouch

Comment: @Valorum  -  it's inside their breather pouch on their utility belt, as written in its description. I omitted it for the same reason I omitted the food capsules.

Comment: The breather is far more interesting than the pouch that it comes in

Comment: @Valorum  -  I have links to Wookipedia, since I that's where I found those pictures. I'll add some sources and the breather

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh7u7.png

Comment: Any chance you can resize those enormous pictures?

Comment: @Valorum  -  I live to serve (is this an acceptable size?)

Comment: Better, although they could still stand to be smaller. I tend to stick to no more than 400px wide and it would improve readability if they were all the same width

Comment: @Valorum  -  I'll do that a bit later then

Comment: Do we actually see handheld imagecasters appear in the original trilogy?  The closest thing I can think of at the moment is the dashboard-mounted unit seen inside the AT-AT in *The Empire Strikes Back*.

Answer (score 3):

Most of this information is taken from Wookieepedia, which I believe bases most of its information on the prequel movies and books. While most of those books are now technically considered "Legacy" books, I would argue this information should still be considered canon unless directly contradicted by the new canon.

They often carried comlinks (as shown by Qui-Gon Jinn in Ep I) to stay in contact with others. They would carry re-breathers (the breathing capsules). They would often carry several days of what are basically advanced energy pills to function as several days worth of field rations. They would also sometimes carry grappling hooks and some form of Metallica rope to assist in climbing surfaces. Less common were small holo projectors, glowsticks, lightsaber repair kit, and some sort of tracking device.

Basically, other than some essentials for survival and navigation, Jedi traveled relying only on their powers and the help of others. They, in keeping with many of their other monastic-like traditions traveled light and shunned material things when they were not necessary.

Comment: Welcome, try and use some sources to back up your answer. Providing evidence will attract upvotes as people see the research you've done and how you've come to reach your conclusions!